# Python selenium doesn't loop through rows

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, openpyxl

I'm very new to Selenium and openpyxl and I'm trying to get data from Excel and insert it into a dynamic web table. My code properly loops through columns of the first Excel row to get the cell values, but when it comes to the second row, it waits for a popup and then closes the window telling me that TimeoutException on "wait_for_popup" occurred. I added try except for that, and now it says that it couldn't find mark_5 variable.

Everything is okay until it comes to the second row.  I guess it doesn't click on the table cell.

Here is the problematic code block :

```
filename = "excel_files\\5b.xlsx"
workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename)
worksheet = workbook['marks']
column = 3
column_reset = 3
row = 1

while row <= 28 :

    while column <= 15 :
        cell_value = worksheet.cell(row, column).value
        if cell_value == 5 :
            row_webtable = str(row)
            column_webtable = str(column)

            retries = 1
            while retries <= 5:
                try:
                    table_cell = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,    '//tbody//tr['+row_webtable+']//td['+column_webtable+']')
                    table_cell.click()
                    wait_for_popup = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[9]/div/div[6]/button[1]')))
                    break
                except TimeoutException:
                    driver.refresh()
                    retries = retries + 1
            mark_5 = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="swal2-html-container"]/div/div[2]/div/div/button[1]')
            mark_5.click()
            time.sleep(0.25)
            submit = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[9]/div/div[6]/button[1]')
            submit.click()            
            time.sleep(sleep_time)
        
        column = column + 1
    column = column_reset 
    row = row + 1
```

Output:

```
PS D:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Projects\selenium_mekdep> & D:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python311/python.exe d:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python311/Projects/selenium_mekdep/main.py

DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:62111/devtools/browser/4765d01c-9079-46d7-9a20-aeac786dfe49
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Projects\selenium_mekdep\main.py", line 173, in <module>
    mark_5 = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="swal2-html-container"]/div/div[2]/div/div/button[1]')
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 740, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {"using": by, "value": value})["value"]
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 346, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "D:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 245, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="swal2-html-container"]/div/div[2]/div/div/button[1]"}
  (Session info: chrome=114.0.5735.134); For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/errors#no-such-element-exception
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
        GetHandleVerifier [0x0110A813+48355]
        (No symbol) [0x0109C4B1]
        (No symbol) [0x00FA5358]
        (No symbol) [0x00FD09A5]
        (No symbol) [0x00FD0B3B]
        (No symbol) [0x00FFE232]
        (No symbol) [0x00FEA784]
        (No symbol) [0x00FFC922]
        (No symbol) [0x00FEA536]
        (No symbol) [0x00FC82DC]
        (No symbol) [0x00FC93DD]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x0136AABD+2539405]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x013AA78F+2800735]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x013A456C+2775612]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x011951E0+616112]
        (No symbol) [0x010A5F8C]
        (No symbol) [0x010A2328]
        (No symbol) [0x010A240B]
        (No symbol) [0x01094FF7]
        BaseThreadInitThunk [0x7595FA29+25]
        RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x76F77BBE+286]
        RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x76F77B8E+238]
```

Actually, it was working properly as I wanted. I thought it stopped working because of the try-except, but when I removed it nothing changed. Could you please help me?